# GROUP BY e SUM no Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, group-by, summary

Estou precisando fazer algo relativamente simples com Crystal Report mas não estou conseguindo.

Tenho um relatório assim:

```
OP   |    CLIENTE   |   PREÇO
1          João          10
1          João          20
1          João          30
2         Marcelo        15
3         Rodrigo        35 
3         Rodrigo        15
4         Pâmela         27
```

E gostaria que aparece assim:

```
OP   |    CLIENTE   |   PREÇO
1          João          60
2         Marcelo        15
3         Rodrigo        50 
4         Pâmela         27
```

Ou seja, agrupar por OPs e somar os preços.

Como faço isso??

Comment: Qual a fonte de dados do relatório ? Uma query com group by resolve isto.

Comment: Sim, na verdade seria até mais simples fazer com a query, mas estou montando o relatório todo com o UI do Crystal Report for Visual Studio e gostaria de saber como fazer exatamente isso através dele.

Comment: @CassioMilanelo Na verdade tem sim. No local onde você seleciona a fonte de dados, provavelmente você deve estar selecionando alguma tabela. Faça previamente uma VIEW no banco de dados e aponte para ela.

Answer (score 1):

**Uma forma de fazer no CR é :**

Insira um Grupo **CLIENTE**

Insira o campo do nome do **Cliente**

Insira as linhas de **detalhe**

Ins1ra um Total (**Botão "somatório**" - Inseir Resumo) , totalize pelo grupo do **CLIENTE**

Coloque a linha detalhe como Ocultar (Botão direito do mouse - **Ocultar Pesquisa Detalhada**)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Motta!

Realmente assim funciona, mas não haveria uma maneira mais prática? No exemplo que dei fica fácil, mas o relatório que  estou montando é bem maior que esse, daria maior trabalho braçal e nada manipulável, sem contar a infinidade de seções que ele adiciona...

Comment: Não me ocorre , mas a melhor forma seria via sql com group by mesmo o CR usaria uma SQL , uma view ou uma procedure retornando cursor.